# OData - query is fine in Chrome, 400 calling with Java

Tags: java, odata

I have unit test code that has run fine for years. And it continues to run fine for every OData query except this one. But suddenly, the url:

http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$select=FirstName&$filter=(BirthDate%20eq%20datetime'1952-02-19T00:00:00Z')

Is returning a 400. My code to call this is:

```
String url = "http://services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Employees?$select=FirstName&$filter=(BirthDate%20eq%20datetime'1952-02-19T00:00:00Z')";
String requestParams = "http.header.Accept=application/json;";
// ...
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(NetUtils.encodeUri(url));
setHeader(httpGet, url, requestParams);
response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
    throw new IOException("Error: " + response.getStatusLine() + ". Reading url " + url);
```

Why is this suddenly a 400? And only when called from Java, works fine in Chrome.

Comment: `NetUtils.encodeUri(url)` - url is already encoded.

Comment: Boy do I feel dumb - yes that's it. Thank you very much. (If you put that as an answer I'm happy to select it.)